# Create a multilingual website

Tags: javascript, android, html, multilingual

I am an experienced Android developer and in my apps I am used to providing multiple string.xml resource files for different languages.

Is there any similar approach to achieve this result for HTML5 websites?

I want to have strings in different languages, and just refer to them by an identifier.

Comment: It's possible if you write a lot of jQuery (class `shouldtranslate`) and use of JSON, but it's not good practice, since users can disable JavaScript, which doesn't degrade gracefully, not to mention it would mean loading the site and layout once for each language. It would be better to use PHP, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store all of your languages in seperate JSON files. The problem would be that with Javascript you would be loading the language file after the page has loaded so you would see the original string briefly before the replacement is added.

HTML

```
<p>LANG:hello</p>
```

JSON file

```
{
    "hello": "bonjeur"
}
```

Javascript

```
// Itentifier would be "hello" 
// Element would be the actual element
// json would be the contents of the JSON file
element.text = json[identifier]
```

A better way would be to use a server side language such as **PHP** so the content is replaced before it is output to the browser.